# C++ Standard Library - std::setenv vs setenv

Tags: c++, c++11, environment-variables

I have a simple call to `std::setenv`, which works fine on my Linux distribution under `gcc`. However, when using `clang` on my Mac OS X, I get the following error.

```
error: no member named 'setenv' in namespace 'std'; did you mean simply 'setenv'?
std::setenv(name.c_str(), value.c_str(), true);
```

I'm sure, I've read somewhere that `setenv` was part of namespace `std` in C++11, but now I'm unsure.

Question: **Should `setenv` or `std::setenv` be used, and why is this the case?**

Answer (score 16):

I do not [find](http://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&search=setenv&go=Go) anything like `std::setenv` on [cppr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/), only [`std::getenv`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/getenv) which in its documentation references the POSIX function [`setenv`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setenv.html), which of course is *not* in `namespace std`.

So since you are not calling a C++ standard function, plain `setenv` should be the way to go since this is how the standard that defines the function defined it. Note that `std::setenv` is allowed (but not required) to work. (See also [hvd's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/743382/hvd).)

For the standard-lovers: `setenv` is only mentioned as

> Calls to the function `getenv` shall not introduce a data race (17.6.5.9) provided that nothing modifies the
>   environment. [ Note: Calls to the POSIX functions `setenv` and `putenv` modify the environment. — end
>   note ]

from N3797 18.10.5. It is indeed not a C++ standard function, thus not necessarily  in `namespace std`.

Comment: The C++ standard doesn't define `setenv`, so if implementations define it anyway as an extension, they can use the global namespace, the `std` namespace, or any other namespace, however they see fit. The OP's implementation that does declare it in the `std` namespace is just as valid as the OP's other implementation that doesn't. (To clarify: I do agree that plain `setenv` is what the OP should use, but your answer comes across as if the fact that `std::setenv` works is a bug.)

Comment: @hvd But lacking further documentation (I do not know of nor find any `setenv` other than the POSIX one), I assumed that he is talking about the POSIX one and wondering if it is also a standard C++ function. Since the POSIX function is not in `namespace std`, the global call would be the general way to access it. While some platforms like apparently gcc on linux adds it to `namespace std`, the standard that defines it does not. Am I wrong?

Comment: @hvd Note also that I never said that `std::setenv` is not allowed to work, just not guaranteed.

Comment: It's not wrong that POSIX defines `setenv` as a global function, but that's mainly because the POSIX standard doesn't define interaction with C++, only with C, and C doesn't have namespaces. There has been work on POSIX C++ bindings in the past, but as far as I know, nothing useful ever came from it, and implementations are left to figure out for themselves how to best provide the POSIX functions to C++ programs.

Comment: @hvd Alright, I clarified to the best of my knowledge. If it is still wrong or not optimal IYO, please feel free to edit or comment or answer yourself or...

Comment: Thank you for your answers. It seems like the ISO has overlooked something very basic if the ability to get environment variables has been standardised (`std::getenv`) while the ability to set environment variables (or interact with them in some other way, e.g., looping) has not.