# Why was getenv standardised but not setenv?

Tags: c++, c, language-lawyer

From answers and comments on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30292642/c-standard-library-stdsetenv-vs-setenv), I understand that [`getenv`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/getenv) is defined by the C++ standard, but `setenv` is not. And indeed, the following program

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

int main ( int argc, char **argv )
{
    std::cout << std::getenv("PATH") << std::endl;  // no errors

    std::setenv("PATH", "/home/phydeaux/.local/bin:...", true);  // error
}
```

does not compile for me (clang 3.9).

Why was one of these seemingly complementary functions standardised but not the other?

Comment: POSIX `setenv()` and `getenv()` aren't thread-safe, IIRC. Maybe somehow related to that?

Comment: @tambre Doubtful, `std::getenv` is threadsafe since C++11 (according to cppreference)

Comment: Speculation, but I'd say is because there is a relatively simple definition of `std::getenv` that can be standardized. String in, string out. The complement is not so straight forward, and is *very* implementation dependent.

Comment: I think it is not standardized because it changes the environment.

Comment: @Borgleader `std::getenv()` itself is thread-safe, **as long** as you don't use any other functions that interact with environment variables (ie. `setenv()`).

Comment: The [C standard mirrors this](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).  There's **7.22.4.6  The `getenv` function**, but no corresponding `setenv()`.  So whatever logic exists for omitting it from C++, it's probably also applicable to C.  Hence I added the C tag. (And the language-lawyer tag...)

Comment: I agree with @StoryTeller's speculation and I guess there's no definitive answer, therefore I'm voting to close as "primarily opinion based", although the question is indeed interesting...

Comment: @FelixPalmen no offense but its not because _you_ don't know the answer and can only speculate that there is not a document somewhere which state the reason why the committee did not standardize `setenv`. Give the question some time to be seen and answered.

Comment: @YSC I'll happily retract that vote if there **is** such a document, but it's quite unlikely.

Comment: @YSC - Rationale documents are usually written wrt to why something *is*, not why something *is not*.

Comment: @StoryTeller In this case, any rationale for including `getenv()` in either the C or C++ standards may be illuminating as to why `setenv()` was omitted, as it's a bit hard to even *have* any type of "environment" for `getenv()` to get values from if there's no way to set those values.

Comment: @AndrewHenle - Who said there even *has* to be an equivalence and an option to set anything? The environment can be whatever, the standard doesn't specify it rather purposefully.

Comment: Well, then find a document. The only answer so far gives a reason without reference and later **literally** includes the words "I guess" ... well, we will see.

Comment: Sad when you search for such a document for 30 minutes but find nothing but POSIX standards. Guess we'll just have to accept "because it isn't".

Comment: @StoryTeller *...the standard doesn't specify it rather purposefully.* If you know it's purposeful, you know the answer...

Comment: @AndrewHenle - By "it" I mean the environment from which said variables are pulled. This is again more of my speculation, but usually not specifying something is just to keep the language as applicable to as many platforms as possible. It's not impossible for said environment to even be immutable.

Comment: I voted to reopen - not that it makes much of a difference - because as it turns out there's a document giving a rationale for omission of a very related function.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The C90 standard includes [`getenv()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getenv.html); therefore, the C++98 standard did too.

When the C standard was originally created, the precedent for environment setting was [`putenv()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/putenv.html); the [`setenv()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setenv.html) function was not devised until later.  The standard committee avoided creating new functions when it could, but also avoided standardizing problematic functions when possible (yes, [`localeconv()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/localeconv.html) and [`gets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/gets.html) are counter-examples).  The behaviour of `putenv()` is problematic.  You have to pass it memory which is not of automatic duration, but you can't know whether you can ever use it again.  It's like a forced memory leak.  It was A Good Thing™ that `putenv()` was not standardized.

The [rationale](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf) for the C standard explicitly says (§7.20.4.5, p163):

> A corresponding `putenv` function was omitted from the Standard, since its utility outside a multi-process environment is questionable, and since its definition is properly the domain of an operating system standard.

Platform-specific APIs step in and provide the missing functionality in a way suitable to them.

---

<sup>The first editions of the POSIX standard (1988 trial use; 1990) did not include `setenv()` or `putenv()`. The X/Open Portability Guide ([XPG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X/Open#Output)) Issue 1 did include `putenv()` based on its appearance in the SVID ([System V Interface Definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_V_Interface_Definition)) — which did not include `setenv()`. The XPG Issue 6 added `setenv()` and `unsetenv()` (see the history sections for the functions at the URLs linked to).  Curiously, on a Mac running macOS Sierra 10.12.6, `man 3 setenv` has a history section that identifies:</sup>

> <sup>The functions setenv() and unsetenv() appeared in Version 7 AT&T UNIX.  The putenv() function appeared in 4.3BSD-Reno.</sup>

<sup>This is unexpected and probably erroneous since the [UNIX Programmer's Manual Vol 1](https://s3.amazonaws.com/plan9-bell-labs/7thEdMan/index.html) (1979) does not include any of `putenv()`, `setenv()` or `unsetenv()`. The `putenv()` function was added to the AT&T variants of Unix at some stage in the 80s; it was in the SVID and documented by the time SVR4 was released in 1990 and may have been part of System III.  I think they almost have the platforms reversed.  [4.3BSD-Reno](http://gunkies.org/wiki/4.3_BSD_Reno) was released in June 1990, after both the first C and POSIX standards were released.</sup>

<sup>There was some discussion in comments with [Random832](https://stackoverflow.com/users/691884/random832) , now removed, mentioning [TUHS – The Unix Heritage Society](http://www.tuhs.org/) as a source of information about ancient versions of Unix.  The chain included my observation: *If nothing else, this discussion emphasizes why the standards committees did well to steer clear of 'setting the environment'! It appears that `putenv()` was not in 7th Edition UNIX, contrary to my memory. I'm fairly sure it was available in a system I used from 1983, which was a lot of 7th Edition with some material from System III, some from PWB. It is a part of SVR4 (I've a manual for that), and was defined in some version of the SVID (probably before SVR4).*</sup>

<sup>The C rationale also mentions concerns about `gets()` but included it despite those concerns; it was (very sensibly) removed from C11, of course (but POSIX still refers to C99, not C11).</sup>

Comment: POSIX apparently [doesn't believe in Good Things](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/putenv.html).  ;-)

Comment: The constraints on POSIX were different from those on C; the result is different choices.

Answer (score 5):

setenv is not possible in some of the original environments `C` was defined for.

getenv allows you to see your environment. creating a new process with exec[lv][p][e] allows you to create a child with an inherited or new environment.

However, setenv, would modify the state of the calling process, which wasn't always possible.

I guess it is because it increases the writable interface for the caller, and was not needed originally, and is a security risk these days.

Comment: "*Modify the state of the **calling** process*" - really?  C could have specified that such platforms (if they exist) provide sufficient isolation in their `getenv()`/`putenv()` implementations to give the effect of per-process environment.

Comment: @TobySpeight: He means, process where the call to `getenv` occurs.

Comment: Ah, I see; I misunderstood as meaning the parent process.  Thanks for pointing that out, @Cheersandhth.-Alf

Comment: @TobySpeight Even regarding what you thought it meant, providing an isolated environment may have been considered too much of a burden on systems that naturally provide a global environment, or no environment at all (a conforming getenv can always return null).